# Writing to QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt, qtextstream

My QTextStream is empty when this code finishes:

```
QString line1 = "This is line one";
QString line2 = "This is line two";
QString line3 = "This is line three";

QString outputFilename = "temp.txt";
QFile outputFile(outputFilename);
outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
outputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);  // This fixes the problem
  QTextStream out1(&outputFile);
   out1  << line1 << endl;
   out1  << line2 << endl;
   out1  << line3 << endl;

outputFile.flush();
QString temp = out1.readAll();           
mainclipboard->setText(temp);
outputFile.close();
```

Here, the QString temp is empty.  What have I missed?

Thanks to hyde for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the file backing the `QTextStream` as write only, so reading should fail for that reason alone. Just change the open mode.

Also consider the position in the file you are reading from... Use `pos()` method to check it, it should tell you that file position is where your write ended. So just `seek()` before reading.

Since you are operating on single `QTextStream`, flushing shouldn't be necessary. If you had separate objects for reading and writing, then you would need to flush to make sure data is written to the OS (flush the `QTextStream`, that also flushes the file, as explained in [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#details)).